# HighCharts - Angular, how to get y axis labels on the vertical lines drawn from x axis

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am looking for the y axis lables on the gridlines in between.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esbyln?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
Currently : [image]

Expected: [image]

Using Angular with highcharts for line charts, applied gridlinewidth and color for grid lines and color
After updating with the changes suggested below - [image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to add labels for the inner grid lines would be to create a dummy series type scatter. This allows you to aim at a precise point on the graph and include only a datalabel for that series which will display the value.

```
  {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [1, 50, 100, 200],
    color: 'transparent',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
```

Now you have to set the added dummy scatter series to be invisible and not respond to mouse movement and not show the tooltip.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
      colorByPoint: false
  },
  scatter: {
      states:{
          inactive:{
              enabled: false
          }
      },
      dataLabels:{
          enabled: true,
          padding: 1,
          allowOverlap: true,
          crop: false,
          overflow: 'allow',
      },
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      showInLegend: false
  },
```

Another way, if you are curious or if the above doesn't satisfy you, is to render the label.
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

---

To select the exactly coordinates of a point, you can use x, y notation.

```
    data: [{x:0, y:1 }, {x:1, y:20}, 100, 200],
```

Comment: With this changes i am getting that y axis labels for only first grid line and not for other lines, how to get that for all the grid lines, attaching that image as well in the question, as i am unable to add that in comments

Comment: You can use x, y notation.